# opening an ifstream file in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string txt="";
    ifstream file;
    file.open ("ernio.txt", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (getline(file, txt)) {
            cout << txt << endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "example" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `example` instead of reading line by line from the file. What am I doing wrong?!? (the file is in the exact same place as the main.cpp) We even tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string txt="";
    ifstream file("ernio.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (getline(file, txt)) {
            cout << txt << endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "example" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help

Comment: "_the file is in the exact same place as the main.cpp_" But, is it in the working directory of your application?

Comment: How do you run the program? Do you run it using an IDE? Or do you run it from the command line?

Comment: You could use the absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 5):

The file needs to be in the directory from where the executable will be called, not in the source directory where your `main.cpp` resides.
When you build small programs with `gcc` or something similar from the command line, often the executable is in the current working directory, where the compiler will also draw the source files from.

When using a build system or an IDE, however, then usually the target of a build is different from that where the sources reside.